# Category of topological pairs?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory

My book uses the abbrevation $\text {Top}^2$. I want to make sure I don't confuse it with the category $\text{Top} \times \text{Top}$.

The topology $\text {Top}^2$ has arbitrary pairs of topological spaces as it's objects and a morphism $(X,Y) \rightarrow (S,T)$ is given by two continuous maps $X \rightarrow Y$ and $S \rightarrow T$.

Is this correct?

Comment: I would be surprised if the notation of these categories was consistent across the mathematical literature. So I would advise you to look carefully at the definitions of notations in whatever you are reading.

Comment: I think $\text{Top}^2$ might mean the category of functors $2\to \text{Top}$? Which are probably the same here, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Jakobian That's right, if $2$ is the discrete category on two objects

Comment: Those two categories ($\text{Top}^2$ and $\text{Top} \times \text{Top}$) are in fact the same category. Perhaps, you might be thinking of the category whose objects are sets $X$ with two topologies $\sigma$ and $\tau$ and whose morphisms $(X_1, \sigma_1, \tau_1) \to (X_2, \sigma_2, \tau_2)$ are functions $X_1 \to X_2$ that are simultaneously continuous from $(X_1, \sigma_1)$ to $(X_2, \sigma_2)$ and from $(X_1, \tau_1)$ to $(X_2, \tau_2)$. Its objects are known as bitopological spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\top}{\mathsf{Top}}$Your category of "pairs" is indeed what $\top^2$ should denote, but please do *not* call this "the category of pairs".

That terminology is (*usually*) reserved for the following category:

> Objects are pairs $(X,A)$ where $X$ is some topological space and $A$ is a subspace of $X$; arrows $(X,A)\to(Y,B)$ are continuous functions $f:X\to Y$ which have $f(A)\subseteq B$.

This is not the same thing as $\top^2$ (well, it's faintly conceivable the two categories are equivalent but this presentation of objects and arrows is decidedly different from that in $\top^2$ and these categories are *in practice* definitely different categories).